# Logic for determining if a user has write access to a folder not working

Tags: c#, acl

I have the following method in a dialog in my application that is intended to determine if a user has write access to a folder:

```
private bool UserCanWriteToFolder( FileSystemNode node ) {
    try {
        WindowsIdentity currentUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal( currentUser );

        DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo( node.FullPath );
        DirectorySecurity acl = directoryInfo.GetAccessControl( AccessControlSections.All );

        AuthorizationRuleCollection rules = acl.GetAccessRules( true, true, typeof( NTAccount ) );

        foreach ( AuthorizationRule rule in rules ) {
            FileSystemAccessRule fsAccessRule = rule as FileSystemAccessRule;
            if ( fsAccessRule == null )
                continue;

            if ( ( fsAccessRule.FileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.WriteData ) > 0 ) {
                NTAccount ntAccount = rule.IdentityReference as NTAccount;
                if ( ntAccount == null )
                    continue;

                if ( principal.IsInRole( ntAccount.Value ) )
                    return true;
            }
        }
    } catch ( Exception ) {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This logic works, but there is a problem.

My user is in the Administrators group.  When I choose the C:\Windows folder, this method returns true, yet, when my program tries to write to the C:\Windows folder, the program throws an UnauthorizedAccessException.  Obviously there's something different about that folder that my code isn't taking into account.

Here's the output of iacls for the C:\Windows folder on my machine:

```
C:\Windows NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:(F)
           NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:(CI)(IO)(F)
           NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(M)
           NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
           BUILTIN\Administrators:(M)
           BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
           BUILTIN\Users:(RX)
           BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)
           CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
           APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES:(RX)
           APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES:(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

Unfortunately, I don't know which line in the ACL is the one that's causing the UnauthorizedAccessException to be thrown.  Can someone point out the problem to me?

Comment: System folders have special protection. In fact, even the `Program Files` folder doesn't allow modifications without running as admin (ie using the `runas` command or the `Run As Administrator` option). *Why* do you want to modify protected folders though? You shouldn't need to make any modifications there

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm reading this in that perhaps a user has selected a system folder (eg in a Save As), and the above check should say they're not allowed to access it, but in fact it is currently saying they can.  It may not be that the OP is actually trying to modify anything here, rather just protect against an `UnauthorizedAccessException` rather than catching it after it's happened.

Comment: @JamesThorpe the OP should handle the exception. UAC strips the admin bit so that even admins can't make changes unless they start an application "as administrator". This can change through settings though, so the existence of Admin entries in ACL doesn't mean that the admin is or isn't able to access the folder.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Oh I agree, the exception should still be handled - the permissions might change between the above check and the action that raises the error etc.

Comment: @JamesThorpe: You are right, I'm trying to prevent the `UnauthorizedAccessException`.  I'm trying to prevent the user from selecting a folder that they can't write to.  It looks like I need to catch the error and handle it with a message and make the user try the operation again if they picked a folder they don't really have write access to, no matter what the above code says.

Comment: I've figured out what my problem was.  I start Visual Studio with admin rights (Run as Administrator) to debug another program in our application suite.  So when it launched the program with this problem, it was running as Administrator, too, so it did indeed have rights to write to the system folders.  If the program is not started with elevated rights, the logic works.  I still need to handle the exception in case security changes between the time the check is made and the error occurs, though.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to abandon the above code.  When I start the program as a normal user, the line that retrieves the ACL throws a `PrivilegeNotHeldException`.  Specifically, the message text reads

> The process does not possess the 'SeSecurityPrivilege' privilege which is required for this operation.

At this point, what I'm going to do is try to create a temporary file in the selected folder.  If that succeeds, I'll delete it and return true.  If that fails (an exception is thrown), I'll return false.  In any case, I have to catch any exceptions that occur when actually writing to the folder and display a useful error message, since, as has been said in the comments, the security could change between this method exits and the write is performed.

Comment: The same is true for many things - eg a call to `File.Exists` might be out of date as soon as it's returned